# Getting parent after finding a node

Tags: xml, vbscript

I'm using VBScript to get nodes, example `//employeeid`. I'm getting list of the nodes with the length greater than 0. Now what I need to do is to get the parent XML of the each node in the node list. I'm trying `../../employeeid` or `parent::invoicenumber`. All returns null or length 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the parent nodes of all nodes `<employeeid>` you could use the following XPath expression:

```
//employeeid/..
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the parent node of a given node, you use the .parentNode property of that node:

```
  Dim sXML   : sXML = Join(Array( _
      "<?xml version=""1.0""?>" _
    , "<humans>" _
    , " <adam>" _
    , "  <children>" _
    , "   <kain></kain>" _
    , "   <abel></abel>" _
    , "  </children>" _
    , " </adam>" _
    , "</humans>" _
  ), vbCrLf)
  Dim oXDoc  : Set oXDoc = CreateObject( "Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0" )
  Dim sXPath : sXPath    = "/humans/adam/children/*"
  oXDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  oXDoc.async = False
  oXDoc.loadXml sXML

  If 0 = oXDoc.ParseError Then
     Dim ndlAdamsChildren : Set ndlAdamsChildren = oXDoc.SelectNodes(sXPath)
     Dim ndChild
     For Each ndChild In ndlAdamsChildren
         WScript.Echo ndChild.tagName, ndChild.parentNode.parentNode.tagName
     Next
  Else
     WScript.Echo oXDoc.parseError.reason
  End If
```

output:

```
kain adam
abel adam
```

**Update wrt Jobbo's comment:**

Use

```
WScript.Echo ndChild.tagName, ndChild.selectSingleNode("../..").tagName
```

(mark the two steps) to get from kain/able to adam via XPath.

Comment: This. Also you could perform XPath queries in the context of ndChild, like: `ndChild.SelectSingleNode("..")` if you prefer to keep everything XPath (I generally do)